# Find all function calls

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am looking for a way to go from a function definition to its call.
It would be the opposite of Go to definition (F12).

I already tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (which works quite well) but this will imply that I have to start already in the line that I want to find.

Comment: You mean like [Find All References](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/11/17/improvements-to-find-all-references-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx?PageIndex=1)?

Comment: There is a call stack debug window.

Comment: Yes, I think it should jump to every place that the function is called. I am just wondering if is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VIsual Studio, then it is really simple:

Right click over your method name and select: "Find all references" (you can also press Ctrl+K,R).

This will show a new window showing all the lines of code that call that specific method (it also shows you the class name and path, as well as line and column of the caller).

Answer (score 12):

you can find all references to a method, using right click Find All References,
or CTRL+K,R.

P.S.
If you are using VS 2013 Ultimate edition, there is also a feature called CodeLens, with which you can easily view and navigate the member references.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn269218.aspx

Answer (score 2):

With ReSharper, you can find all references to a method/field/variable/type/etc with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

The popup offers lots of advanced search options:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In VS2012 right click on the function / `Find usages`

Answer (score 1):

In Visual-Studio 2012, I use "View Call Hierarchy", which has a shortcut `CTRL-K,T`